# Firebase-Dart Filtering Data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dart

My data is something like this:

```
{
  "members": [
    {
      "type": "alpha",
      "name": "John"
    },
    {
      "type": "alpha",
      "name": "Jane"
    },
    {
      "type": "beta",
      "name": "Renata"
    },
      { 
      "type": "beta",
      "name": "Richard"
    }
  ]
}
```

If I access it as follows, I get the list of all members:

```
DatabaseReference ref = database().ref('members')
ref.onValue.listen((e) {
  var members = e.snapshot.val();
});
```

However, if I try to filter the data, as follows, I get `null`.

```
DatabaseReference ref = database().ref('members').orderByValue().equalTo("alpha", "type");
ref.onValue.listen((e) {
  var members = e.snapshot.val();
});
```

How do I get only objects with "type" "alpha"?

Answer (score 2):

Your `members` reference corresponds to a `List` of objects, and none of the immediate children in the `List` are strings like `"alpha"` so your `orderByValue().equalTo()` query returns `null`. The `"type"` argument you're passing is searching on indices in the list (`0`, `1`, etc.) rather than keys in the child objects (`"type"`, `"name"`).

Instead, you can use `orderByChild()`:

```
DatabaseReference ref = database().ref().child('members').orderByChild("type").equalTo("alpha");
```

You may find that you get a `List` with some holes in it, if the alphas aren't at the beginning:

```
[{name: John, type: alpha}, null, {name: Jane, type: alpha}]
```

You can remove the `null` values with

```
  members = new List<Object>.from(members)..remove(null);
```